# Geometry of nose in and nose out parking in parking lots

Tags: computational-geometry

I would like some computational evidence in favor of my observation that one can park a car in tighter (parking lot) spaces by backing in rather than nose in. I have been doing this successfully for some 15 years, but see few others trying this.

So, the model is a rectangular parking space, orthogonal to the side of the lot, and a second row of cars blocking the way, opposite the space. A car has fixed wheels in back, maybe at 1/4 the length, and turning wheels in front, maybe also 1/4 the length, I don't know. I see people going in and out trying to get into spaces (nose in) that I would have gotten first try. If there were no second row of cars narrowing things, of course they could, essentially make a turn and then simply drive in a straight line into the space. But that is not how parking lots are made. A given car has a minimum turning radius, but the main point is that the center of the circle may not be where one expects.

In the long run, I would love to have something I can show to Berkeley Bowl West and Trader Joe's suggesting that they put up signs "Consider parking by backing In."

Comment: Is `ask-orourke` a real tag?

Comment: For the moment it is. It wasn't a real tag until I typed it in as such.

Comment: It is well known that it is easier to parallel park in reverse as the front end of the car can change position faster at the end of the turn

Comment: @Henry, exactly right.

Comment: This is half of the reason that fork-lifts always put the steering wheels at the rear (opposite the forks).

Comment: @CarlBrannen What is the other half of the reason?

Comment: The front wheels of a fork-lift have to carry the heavier load. So it's an easier design if you make the load-bearing wheels not able to turn.

Comment: In fact, in Japan, where space is at a premium and parking lots are quite small, everyone parks backing in, nearly 100% of the time, for the reasons you mentioned.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sorry to disappoint despite the (now removed) eponymous tag :-), but in fact I don't
have a precise answer.  Here are three possible sources, the second two mathematical.

(1) "You're Parking Wrong:
Why it's almost always better to back into a space than pull into it head-on."
Tom Vanderbilt, *Slate*, Feb. 2011. ([Article link](http://www.slate.com/articles/life/transport/2011/02/youre_parking_wrong.html).)

(2) "Mathematical Analysis of the Parallel Parking Problem,"
William A. Allen,
*Mathematics Magazine*,
Vol. 34, No. 2 (Nov.-Dec., 1960), pp. 63-66. ([JSTOR link](http://www.jstor.org/pss/2689321).)

(3) "The Geometry of Perfect Parking,"
Simon R. Blackburn,
2009. ([Web link leading to PDF link](http://www.ma.rhul.ac.uk/SRBparking).)

The two math papers concentrate on parallel parking, which is not your question,
but is nevertheless quite interesting.
Here is a nice figure from Allen's paper:

            
[image]

Comment: Thanks, Joseph. Just so you do not feel you are the only one summoned unfairly, or the first,  see   http://mathoverflow.net/questions/69542/uniformly-convex-spaces

Comment: these kinds of curves appear in **contact geometry**.  See [What is a Legendrian Knot?](http://www.ams.org/notices/200910/tx091001282p.pdf)